# How to change View of the Activity from within the ViewPager's Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I need to change a `TextView'`s text that is placed in the layout of my `FragmentActivity` that has a `ViewPager` and a `ViewPagerAdapter`. Basically I have created an action bar in my application that presents the name of the current visible `Fragment`.

So I need this `TextView` to be changed on each change of the visible fragment in the `ViewPager` (either with the swipe motion or selected using the `TabHost`). From my search I found that this method should help me achieve my goal:

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint invoked!");
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) 
    {
        if (odTab != null && getActivity() != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Currently visable tab: "+odTab.getTabTitle());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Currently visable tab: "+odTab.getTabTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (application.getCurrentDataSource() == DataSource.SSRS)
            {
                if (rsTab.getTabTitle().equals("")  || rsTab.getTabTitle() == null)
                {
                    tabName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    tabName.setText(rsTab.getTabTitle());
                }
            }
            else if (application.getCurrentDataSource() == DataSource.SGRDL)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "found Title textView from fragmentActivity");
                if (odTab.getTabTitle().equals("")  || odTab.getTabTitle() == null)
                {
                    ((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tvTabName).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "set Title textView to: "+odTab.getTabTitle());
                    ((TextView) ((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tvTabName)).setText(odTab.getTabTitle());
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I tried to implement it in my fragment but for some reason this line:

```
((TextView) ((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tvTabName)).setText(odTab.getTabTitle());
```

doesn't do anything although this line do get presented in the log for each change of fragment in the viewPager:

```
Log.d(TAG, "set Title textView to: "+odTab.getTabTitle());
```

UPDATE:
My adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
private List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}  
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? is there another way to do this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally managed to deal with this issue is combined with a few things:

**1.** First I declared an interface in my fragment:

```
public interface OnFragmetVisibleListener{
    public void fragmetVisible(boolean visible);
}
```

**2.** Next I added this function as well to the fragment to know when it's attached to the `ViewPager`:

```
@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity){ 
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        onFragmetVisibleListener = (OnFragmetVisibleListener) activity;
        isAttached = true; //flag for whether this framgnet is attache to pager
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement interface OnFragmetVisibleListener");
    }
}
```

**3.** I added the following method as well to know when the fragment is visible and set it's data object in the `Application` class:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint invoked!");
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) 
    {
        if (odTab != null && getActivity() != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Currently visable tab: "+odTab.getTabTitle());
            application.currentVisibleTab = odTab;
        }
        if (isAttached)
        { 
            onFragmetVisibleListener.fragmetVisible(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

**4.** In my `ViewPager`'s activity I let it implement the defined interface in step 1:

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GridFragment.OnFragmetVisibleListenerr
```

**5.** Next I added the unimplemented method:

```
@Override
public void fragmetVisible(boolean visible) 
{
    if(visible)
    {
        setCurrentTabTitle(application.currentVisibleTab.getTabTitle());
    }
}
```

**6.** when `setCurrentTabTitle` is:

```
 public void setCurrentTabTitle(String title)
{
    tvTabTitle.setText(title); //my TextView that's needs to be changed.
    Log.d(TAG, "set tab title from activity: "+title);
}
```

And that is it, this is how I changed a view of the activity depending on the visible fragment of the `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 3):

In your activity you can do:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                // Change your textview
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: I already have this in my activity, the problem is that the tabs title/name is stored in an object inside the fragment. so I need to get the right fragment, get this object from it, extract it name and apply it to the textview. and by now i didn't managed to do this.

Comment: ok. with viewPager.getChildAt(index) you can get the fragment view. You can add a hidden view (add a tag with your information) in fragment and get the view in activity.

Comment: please see updated question, I was wrong and the method I used do gets invoked I only can't change the text of the TextView of the FragmentActivity from within the Fragment

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't pinpoint the problem, I would suggest to simplify your code:

1. avoid cast within cast. You use `TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity` both in `if` and `else`. assign this cast to a parameter and use this parameter. The processing overhead worth it.
2. instead of using `findViewById`, save `R.id.tvTabName` as a local parameter in `TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity` and create a method `setTitle(String title)` in `TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity`. It will also help you to debug this call at the activity itself.
3. I agree with @mromer - try to access the fragment from the activity. To achieve this, make your `FragmentPagerAdapter` inherit the following class:

```java
public abstract class SmartFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SparseArray<String> mFragmentTags;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public SmartFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        mFragmentTags = new SparseArray<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            // record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    // use this method in onPageSelected
    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag == null)
            return null;
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
        return mFragmentManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: about 1: you are right, I will change it. 2: I have this method in my TabsActivity and the code reaches this part, but for some reason it doesn't change then text in the TextView. 3: I already have an implementation of a FragmentPagerAdapter, only it's implemented in a different way (with List of fragments and not a SparseArray of string Tags.) I posted it's implementation in the question body.